# Given final block not properly padded - Dataloader password verification Error

Tags: data-loader

I am trying to set up Dataloader in CLI Mode .

I generated the Encrypted key and Encrypted password.
When I am trying to verify that using

```
encrypt.bat -v generatedPassword secretKey
```

or

`encrypt.bat –v <Encrypted password> <salesforce password>`

-as mentioned somewhere

It's throwing  errors:

> Error decrypting string
>
> Given final block not properly padded

What could be the possible reasons that I should look into?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the right syntax:-

```
encrypt.bat –v Encrypted password salesforcePassword pathtokeyfile
```

You can check its usage by using 'encrypt.bat --help' or 'encrypt --help' on terminal.